# Best practices to control buttons like update save and delete for sqlite in android

Tags: android, sqlite, button

I want to have some edittexts and listview for data and buttons like add,update and delete. What is the best practice for controlling the buttons to be enabled or not, using a public method like..

```
public void CheckButtonStates(int Condition, List<ImageButton> tmlist)
{


    switch (Condition)
    {
        case 1://Start

            tmlist.get(0).setEnabled(true);//save button
            tmlist.get(1).setEnabled(false);//update button
            tmlist.get(2).setEnabled(false);//delete button
            tmlist.get(0).setAlpha(1f);
            tmlist.get(1).setAlpha(0.4f);
            tmlist.get(2).setAlpha(0.4f);
            break;
        case 2://Add new
            tmlist.get(0).setEnabled(true);//save button
            tmlist.get(1).setEnabled(false);//update button
            tmlist.get(2).setEnabled(true);//delete button
            tmlist.get(0).setAlpha(1f);
            tmlist.get(1).setAlpha(0.4f);
            tmlist.get(2).setAlpha(1f);                          
            break;
}
```

or there is another way more efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to control this situation is to control the visibility or the enabled of the buttons from buttons click.

When the app starts you have your edittexts empty and save button enable in order to save new data in sqlite database.
When your user click something from the listview take the data from selected list item fill the edittexts and set disable the save button and enable update and delete button.
When user click delete or update button save or delete data in sqlite and set your edittext fields empty and enable save button and disable update and delete buttons.

Example:

```
btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                //Save data to sqlite
                //Set your edittexts empty
                btnUpdate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnDelete.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnSave.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a listener for each button and decide which functions should not be able due to the last function,it all depends on your needs. like this:

```
    UpdateButton.setonclickListener(new.....)
{
           //onclick:{
              updateButton.setEnabled(true);

           }

 }
```

Hope you understand what I tried to do,if not tell me and I will update a full code.